# Getting the first 6 strings in a string array in VB

Tags: arrays, string, vb.net, treeview

I have a String array which gets all the files from a directory. `Dim files() as string = IO.Directory.GetFiles(xxx)` 
These files are being added as nodes on a TreeView. The issues I am having is, when there are 300 files in the array. I loop through and get each file and add all 300 to the Treeview. But I want to only get the first 100 files from the array and only add those. I feel like this should be pretty simple but trying to figure out how to get the first 100 strings(files) from the array is slipping my mind. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Dim firstFiles() as string = IO.Directory.GetFiles(...).Take(6)` or 100 or 13 whatever strikes your fancy

Comment: Count them... or use [Take](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

**Opt 1) Use `take()`**

```
Dim files() as string = IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\Temp").Take(6)
```

**Opt 2) Use a for loop**

```
Dim files() as string = IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\Temp")
For i as Integer = 0 to 5
    TreeView1.Nodes.Add(files(i))
Next
```

Comment: Welcome!  Please mark as the answer if it solved your needs.

Comment: If you use the For Loop, add an extra check to make sure "i" is less than the returned number of files!

Comment: Doesn't opt 1 need a `ToArray()` on the end?